# Activating a WCSession in viewDidLoad - What bugs might this introduce?

Tags: ios, watchkit

In the *Introducing Watch Connectivity* session at WWDC, it was recommended that you don't activate a WCSession instance in a viewDidLoad method in case your app is loaded in the background. So the following isn't advised:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if(WCSession.isSupported()){
        watchSession = WCSession.defaultSession()
        watchSession!.delegate = self
        watchSession!.activateSession()
    }
}
```

Could someone elaborate on the problems that this might cause?

Is the issue that your app wouldn't be reacting to messages from the session if you have background code, or that the app could be relaunched from the background, the session could have been shut down while in the background, and the view could be displayed without a further call to viewDidLoad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old question but in case anyone wants to know why: because if your app wasn't running when the Watch app was started, your app will be launched in the background on the iOS device. And when launched in the background, your app does NOT have its UI started. So no viewDidLoads will ever launch, and your iOS app will never activate its WCSession, which means the Watch app will never be able to talk to your iOS device unless the iOS app is already running.